# Write an executor service to process in a batch of 100 records

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-s3, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

```
private void startProcess() throws Exception {

        ListObjectsV2Request listObjectsV2Request = new ListObjectsV2Request();
        listObjectsV2Request.setBucketName(bucket);
        listObjectsV2Request.setPrefix(prefix);
        ListObjectsV2Result listObjectsV2Result;

        do {
            listObjectsV2Result = s3Client.listObjectsV2(listObjectsV2Request);
            execute(listObjectsV2Result.getObjectSummaries());
            listObjectsV2Request.setContinuationToken(listObjectsV2Result.getNextContinuationToken());
        } while(listObjectsV2Result.isTruncated());

    }


    public void execute(List<S3ObjectSummary> s3ObjectSummaries) throws Exception{
        List<List<S3ObjectSummary>> results = partition(s3ObjectSummaries, 100);

        List<Future<?>> futureResults = new ArrayList<>();
        for (List<S3ObjectSummary> summaries : results) {
            futureResults.add(executor.submit(() -> {
                process(summaries);

                return true;
            }));
        }
        for (Future<?> asyncResult : futureResults) {
            asyncResult.get();
        }
    }

    private List<List<S3ObjectSummary>> partition(List<S3ObjectSummary> list, Integer partitionSize) {
        int numberOfLists = BigDecimal.valueOf(list.size())
                .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(partitionSize), 0, CEILING)
                .intValue();

        return IntStream.range(0, numberOfLists)
                .mapToObj(it -> list.subList(it * partitionSize, Math.min((it+1) * partitionSize, list.size())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

The above code fetches 1000 records for every next token. I wanted to process 1000 records by splitting into batches of 100 and every 100 records being submitted as a task to the executor thread service. So there should be 10 thread pools and each pool executing 100 records asynchronously.  Is there any example that could help my scenario? Should I iterate 1000 records and put them in a map first. For each 100th record in the iteration, I submit the map to the executor service and flush the map for the next iteration onwards?  Is it the right approach? any suggestions?

Comment: You need a thread pool containing 10 threads and not 10 thread pools. Approach sems about right to me. Show us the code you want to use tho so we can comment more on it.

Comment: @Amongalen added the code piece. I hope the approach is a good one.

Comment: @Amongalen I don't want the thread to stop if there is an exception or error thrown while processing any one of the object summaries. how will I make sure the thread does not stop and it continues if there is an exception. Maybe if I am exception is thrown, I would want to log an exception without stopping the thread?